# ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index despite being the proper size

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I'm attempting to insert a column into my dataframe. This is my code:

```
Dissociaton_Constant_Table=pd.DataFrame(Dissociation_Constant)
Dissociaton_Constant_Table.columns=['kD', 'Standard Deviation', 'R2']
File_names_array=np.array(File_Names)
print(len(File_names_array))
print(Dissociaton_Constant_Table.shape)
Dissociaton_Constant_Table.insert(0,'Files',[File_names_array])
```

This is what File_names is:

```
['first.txt', 'second.txt', 'third.txt', 'fourth.txt', 'fifth.txt', 'sixth.txt']
```

and this is what the print outputs for the sizes of the column I'm trying to add, and my datatable are:

```
6
(6, 3)
```

So it is the appropriate size to be able to fit in, so I don't exactly know what the problem is. I've tried to reshape it (from a 1D array of 6 to a 2D array of (6,1), but this didn't work). As you can see, File_names is originally a list, so I changed it to an array, but that also didn't resolve the issue. So at this point, I don't know why I'm getting the error I'm getting. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i am assuming you want to add the new column `'Files'`. you can just assign it like this `Dissociaton_Constant_Table['Files'] = File_names_array`

Comment: But I specifically want to add it in the 0th position on my data table (i.e. in front of all the other columns). Also, why would that line work, but the code I have above not work?

Comment: remove the square brackets around `File_names_array`. `Dissociaton_Constant_Table.insert(0,'Files',File_names_array)`

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Inserting - you are inserting incorrectly since there's no need in brackets, your 
 **File_names_array** is **already an array** it should be done like this:

```
Dissociaton_Constant_Table.insert(0,'Files',File_names_array)
```

Also, if there's no need in placing it in a particular place - you may use:

```
Dissociaton_Constant_Table['Files'] = File_names_array
```